# Changing the shared memory size of a container instance in Amazon ECS

Tags: memory, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, container

As much as I've found container instances run with a default 64MB of shared memory (shm) and it is possible to change that amount using the `--shm-size` argument with the `docker run` command.
Now I want to run a docker image on Amazon ECS with a custom amount of shared memory.
Does anyone know a way to do this? Is it possible to pass the `--shm-size` argument to the ecs docker machine?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, at time of writing (17 May 2017), it is not yet supported. See the progress on

- https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/787
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=718167

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory size is now supported:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/amazon-ecs-adds-support-for-shm-size-and-tmpfs-parameters/

Documentation is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_linuxparameters

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: He did a great job, the information inside the link is literally only "shm" is enabled: `You can now use the Docker shm-size and tmpfs parameters in Amazon Elastic Container Service (Amazon ECS) task definitions.` .